# The only rotation fields satisfying this PDE are constant

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde, orthogonal-matrices

$\newcommand{\div}{\operatorname{div}}$$\newcommand{\SO}{\operatorname{SO(2)}}$$\newcommand{\R}{\operatorname{\mathbb{R}}}$$\newcommand{\bdx}{\partial_x}$$\newcommand{\bdy}{\partial_y}$$\newcommand{\til}{\tilde}$
Let $\Omega \subseteq \R^2$ be an open connected domain, and let $U,V :\Omega \to \SO$ be smooth maps.

> Claim: Suppose that $$ \div \bigg(U\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\\ 0 & b \end{pmatrix} V^T\bigg)=0 \tag{1}$$
> for any $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, where $\div$ is the standard divergence operator, acting row-by-row. Then $U,V$ are constant.

*Comment:* The assumption is equivalent to the following statement: For any  diagonal matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\\ 0 & b \end{pmatrix}$, the field $U\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\\ 0 & b \end{pmatrix}V^T$ equals $df$ for some smooth map $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

---

I provide a proof below. I wonder whether there is a more conceptual or geometric proof. In particular, I don't "see a reason" for the appearance of complex analysis, which somehow arises in the proof.

---

*Proof:*

Set $$U=\begin{pmatrix} c & -s \\\ s & c \end{pmatrix}=R_{\theta}, V^T=\begin{pmatrix} \til c & - \til s \\\ \til s & \til c \end{pmatrix}=R_{\tilde \theta}.$$ Writing the system $(1)$ explicitly, we get
$$
 \begin{pmatrix} \bdx(c\til c) -\bdy(c\til s) & -\bdx(s\til s) -\bdy(\til c s) \\\ \bdx(s\til c)- \bdy(s \til s) & \bdx( \til s c) + \bdy(c \til c) \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a   \\\ b \end{pmatrix}=0,
$$

so

$$
\begin{split}
&\partial_x(\tilde sc)=-\partial_y(c\tilde c) \\
 &\partial_y(\tilde s c)=\partial_x(c\tilde c) \\
\end{split} \tag{2}
$$

$$
\begin{split}
&\partial_x(s\tilde c)=\partial_y(s\tilde s) \\
&\partial_y(s\tilde c)=-\partial_x(s\tilde s).
\end{split} \tag{3}
$$

The systems $(2),(3)$ are equivalent to the holomorphicity of  $$f=-\tilde sc+i(c\tilde c)=i\cos(\theta)e^{i\tilde \theta},\,\,\,g=s\tilde c+i(s\tilde s)=\sin(\theta)e^{i\tilde \theta}.$$

Thus $(if)^2+g^2=e^{2i\tilde \theta}$ is holomorphic. Since its image lies on a circle, the open mapping theorem implies that it is constant, thus $e^{i\tilde \theta}$ is constant.

Together with the holomorphicity of $f,g$, we deduce that $c=\cos(\theta), s=\sin(\theta)$ are holomorphic, so are also constant.

---

Is there a simpler proof? Was this fact "obvious" -- could we somehow prove its without expanding $U,V$ explicitly in terms of $c,s,\tilde c,\tilde s$?

Comment: I don't have time right now to do the necessary calculations to give a detailed answer. But I think some spin will show up. For example  a similar approach to surfaces into euclidean 3-space is used by Pinkall and Schröder (together with some coauthors) to construct surfaces from a parametrised plane. It might be that your equations are just the special case where the surface remains planar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*NB*: Evidently I used a different convention on divergence. In terms of matrix components my convention is $(\mathrm{div} M)_j = \sum_{i = 1}^2 \partial_{x^i} M_{ij}$. If your convention is $\sum_{i = 1}^2 \partial_{x^i} M_{ji}$, then everywhere I multiplied the divergence on the right by something, you should multiply on the left by the corresponding thing.

---

You don't even need all $a,b$. Let $I$ be the identity matrix and $R = \mathrm{diag}(1,-1) \in O(2)$ is the reflection matrix.

With the diagonal being $I$, you have
$$ \mathrm{div}(UV^T) = 0 $$
with the diagonal being $R$, you have
$$ \mathrm{div}(UR V^T) = 0 \iff \mathrm{div}(URV^T R) = 0 $$
the latter because you are just multiplying on the right with a constant, full rank, matrix so it commutes with taking the divergence.

Notice that $RV^TR = V$ by the conjugate action of the reflection on $SO(2)$.

Locally we can lift $U, V$ to mappings to the Lie algebra, and since $SO(2)$ is abelian we have that for some real valued functions $u,v$

$$ U = \exp(i u), \quad V = \exp(i v) $$

and that $UV^T = \exp(i(u-v))$ and $UV = \exp(i(u+v))$.

You have that
$$ 0 = \mathrm{div}(UV^T) VU^T = (id(u-v))^T $$
and similarly
$$ 0 = \mathrm{div}(UV) V^T U^T = (id(u+v))^T $$
adding and subtracting you find $du = dv = 0$.

Comment: My convention is that $\mathrm{div} M = (\partial_x, \partial_y)^T M$. This corresponds to $\nabla^i M_{ij}$. If after the divergence you end up with a column vector, you are acting on the right, so you should flip all the right multiplications to left multiplication... so where I conjugated on the right with the reflection by $R$ you should conjugate on the left instead.

Comment: (I thought when you say "acting row by row" you meant taking $\partial_x$ of first row, and $\partial_y$ of second row...)

Comment: Basically, if you $f:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ and $F = exp(if)$ where $i = (0, -1; 1,0)$, you have that the tensor $\nabla_a F_{bc} = \nabla_a f (i F)_{bc} = \nabla_a f (F i)_{bc}$. And so if you want to contract $ac$ instead of $ab$, you can multiply on the left by $(F^T)_{db}$.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and clarifications. If I did not make any mistake, then assuming your convention, I got that if $R=e^{ir}$, then  $(\text{div}(R))R^{-1}=-(\partial_x r) dy+(\partial_y r) dx$, which is not exactly your claimed $(\text{div}(R))R^{-1}=dr$, but gives the same conclusion.  (Quite embarrassingly, I am not fluent in abstract index notation, so I really just tried to do everything here by hand; that should be entirely doable, since we are in dimension $2$ after all...).

Comment: Re 2up: that was my mistake. $\frac{d}{dx} e^{ix} = i e^{ix}$, I dropped the $i$. // Re 1up: general fact about Lie groups. Let $\mathfrak{G}$ be a lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra. Fix $g\in \mathfrak{g}$ and given a function $r: \Omega\to \mathbb{R}$, then you have $(\mathrm{d} \exp(r g) ) \exp(-rg)= \mathrm{d}r\otimes g$. For divergence, you contract, and so $g$ acts on $dr$ by multiplication (on the left or on the right, by your choice).

Comment: Thanks, your last comment is very interesting; let's write $ R=\exp(r g)$. I agree that $(\mathrm{d} R ) R^{-1}= \mathrm{d}r\otimes g$, so if $\mathrm{d} R=0$, then $\mathrm{d}r=0$. However as you say, here we don't exactly have $\mathrm{d} R=0$ but $\text{div}(R)=\text{tr}(\nabla R)=0$, which involves some contraction of the total derivative $\nabla R$--which considers $R$ as a map $\Omega \to \text{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2)$. (while $\mathrm{d} R$ views $R$ as a map $\Omega \to \text{SO}(2)$). I wonder whether there is a nice way to see that we don't lose information

Comment: by passing from $\mathrm{d} R=0$ to $\text{div}(R)=0$; part of the complication is that the $\text{div}$ operator actually acts on the larger space $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2)$. Of course, writing $R=\begin{pmatrix} c & -s \\\ s & c \end{pmatrix}$ one can see that if $\text{div}(R)=0$, then $c,s$ satisfy the CR equations, hence are constant, but In general $\mathrm{d} R$ contains more information than $\text{div}(R)$.

Comment: $\nabla R$ is certainly not generic in $Hom(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R}^2)$. You cannot just forget that $R$ takes values on a one dimensional manifold: as a $2\times 2$ matrix $\nabla R$ must be rank 1.